# How to connect to JMX server running inside WSL2

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jmx, visualvm, wsl-2

I'm running my Java application with the following parameters that enable JMX server's remote connections:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9998
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I can successfully connect to that JMX server via VisualVM by adding a new JMX Connection to address: `<HOSTNAME>:9998`

But when i run that application inside Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) Visual VM cannot connect to `localhost:9998`:
[connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9pEE.png)

For what I know, every port that the application is listening on in WSL2 is also opened in host machine (Windows itself), and I can check that using `Win+R -> cmd -> telnet localhost 9998` (connected successfully).
Also, I'm running an nginx instance inside WSL2 that I can connect to by any browser on my host machine (Windows) using `localhost`.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to get Windows jconsole to connect to a JVM running in WSL2 using any of the suggestions above, however it is now possible to run Linux jconsole in WSL2, using [Windows 11's Linux GUI support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps). Works perfectly.

Comment: Do you mean this? [Run Linux GUI apps on the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and finally I found a working set of properties for my WSL2. Additionally I had additional requirement to set it up for docker container running inside WSL2, while JConsole/VisualVM was running on Windows host. I have also a VPN running which probably mess up networking even more.

I found this application https://github.com/cluther/jmx-tester to be useful in debugging the connection.

### inside WSL2

```
java \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9991 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-jar jmx-tester-1.0.0.jar
```

Then on Windows host connect JMX to `127.0.0.1:9991`

### docker container inside WSL2

```
java \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=0.0.0.0 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9991 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9991 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-jar jmx-tester-1.0.0.jar
```

Then on Windows host connect JMX to `127.0.0.1:9991`

Comment: +1 for mentioning "java.rmi.server.hostname" (which was what I needed, while the other more recent answers seem to lack) to be able to connect from Windows to WSL2. I wonder if the host, when telling the client which port to use, also sends the IP/hostname to connect to, and without setting that property in my case it was something else than localhost.

Comment: OMG this actually worked! Thanks a lot. How the hell did you figure it out??

Answer (score 1):

In my case it depends on `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

Default value is false

I have server running on WSL2 and client running on Win11:

```
c:>java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=system my.My2 http://localhost:8025
http://localhost:8025
{"timestamp":"2022-04-22T10:25:03.819+00:00","status":"404","error":"Not Found","path":"/"}

c:>java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true my.My2 http://localhost:8025
http://localhost:8025
{"timestamp":"2022-04-22T10:25:14.544+00:00","status":"404","error":"Not Found","path":"/"}

c:>java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false my.My2 http://localhost:8025
http://localhost:8025
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:571)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
        at my.My2.main(My2.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
...

c:>java  my.My2 http://localhost:8025
http://localhost:8025
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:571)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
        at my.My2.main(My2.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general issue with Java.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/6253

A workaround that worked for me was listening on '0.0.0.0' instead of '127.0.0.1' in WSL2 with the JMX server.

Comment: do you mean using `-D=com.sun.management.jmxremote.host=0.0.0.0`?